# Meanings of pathetic words (derived from πάθος)

Tags: etymology, greek

Originally, [pathos (πάθος)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathos) meant "suffering" and "pain". Today, there are (at least) three main branches of meaning:

- *pathological* (having to do with desease) as in [pathology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathology), [psychopathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopathy), [sociopathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopathy#Sociopathy), [neuropathology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuropathology)
- *empathic* (having to do with care) as in [empathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy), [sympathy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathy)
- *rhetoric* as in [pathetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathos)

I wonder when (how, why) these branchings of meaning did occur.

Besides this coarse-grained question I wonder what exactly is the difference between **empathy** and **sympathy**. At the surface it seems clear: I can be empathic with people I don't like (don't have sympathy with), but not the other way around, or do I? Why and how did these two words (and their referents) evolve?

Comment: I write under correction from Real Scholars of Greek, but I believe that the verb from which *path-* derives wasn't about 'suffering' only in the sense of experiencing pain but more largely in the sense of undergoing or experiencing anything, good or bad, including 'emotions' and 'passions'--whose Latin roots similarly express being the object of an action.

Comment: totally irrelevant, but is the cedilla derived from the Greek 's'?

Comment: No, the cedilla, originally used in Spanish, derives from the letter 'z'.

Answer (score 2):

These are obviously scholarly derivations introduced in Early Modern English ([pathology is attested in the 17th century](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pathology)). It was a time of advances in knowledge and there was a need for new technical words; Greek and Latin roots were used for that purpose.

There is an earlier analogue that made it into Middle English, which comes from Latin: *passion* (in its original meaning of "suffering" as in the *Passion of Christ*), which is connected to the Latin verb *[pati](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=passion)* (to suffer) perhaps akin to the Greek word. You may [find a study of the word here](http://www.biblestudytools.com/encyclopedias/isbe/passion-passions.html), in connection with the Bible.